# Is Possible to make program or software to convert source android app to ios app version by one click?

Tags: android, ios

i have develop more than 30 android app and now our clients need ios version of those apps can anyone developer make an tools to do this by uploading android source code to this tool to perform by conversation to ios version

Comment: what are the android apps written in

Comment: Some Android Java code can be transpiled into Objective-C with [J2ObjC](https://developers.google.com/j2objc/). It might not be that useful if/as you didn't have that conversion in mind already when designing your applications. It could work for some "business logic" code. Anything UI related needs to be re-written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible for one click.
You need write native application or use cross-platform framework like react-native, xamarin but in this variant better rewrite current application